# Find All Permutations of String in Scala

Tags: scala, combinatorics

I created the following function, `permutations`, to produce all permutations of a `List[A]`.

Example:

```
scala> net.Permutations.permutations("ab".split("").toList)
res3: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b), List(b, a))
```

Code:

```
object Permutations {

  def permutations[A](str: List[A]): List[List[A]] =
    str match {
      case Nil => List(Nil)
      case list @ _ :: _ =>
        val shifteds: List[List[A]] =
          shiftN(list, list.length)

        shifteds.flatMap {
          case head :: tail =>
            permutations(tail).map { lists: List[A] =>
              head :: lists
            }
          case Nil => Nil
        }
    }

  private def shiftN[A](list: List[A], n: Int): List[List[A]] = {
    if (n <= 0) Nil
    else {
      val shifted: List[A] = shift(list)
      shifted :: shiftN(shifted, n - 1)
    }
  }

  private def shift[A](arr: List[A]): List[A] = arr match {
    case head :: tail => tail ++ List(head)
    case Nil => Nil
  }
}
```

I think it's correct since the following property-based check succeeds:

```
import munit.ScalaCheckSuite
import org.scalacheck.Prop._
import org.scalacheck.Gen

class PermutationsSpec extends ScalaCheckSuite {

  private val listGen: Gen[List[Int]] =
    for {
      n <- Gen.choose(0, 7)
      list <- Gen.listOfN(n, Gen.posNum[Int])
    } yield list


  property("permutations works") {
    forAll(listGen) { list: List[Int] =>
      val mine: List[List[Int]] = Permutations.permutations(list)
      val stdLib: List[List[Int]] = list.permutations.toList
      assert(stdLib.diff(mine).isEmpty)
    }
  }

}
```

Please evaluate for correctness, concision and performance.

Comment: Your definition of _permutation_ differs from that of the Scala standard library: `permutations(List(1,2,2)).length` vs `List(1,2,2).permutations.length`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks to be correct, yes, the testing looks good too.  I was
thinking whether `List(List())` for the input `List()` makes sense, but
it seems like that's a sensible output.

For the code readability I'd rename `str`, especially since it's not
really a string, but a `list`.  The complicated match expression in
`permutations` can just be simplified to `case _` and in the body the
original argument can be reused again.

I'd also inline `shifteds` value since it's just a single call and the
name doesn't really tell me anything.  On that note, docstrings for the
functions might be a nice touch, especially for the `shift` and `shiftN`
methods.

The unused case labels can also just be `_` everywhere.  Depends of
course, for me this makes it clearer that really there's always just two
cases, either matching an empty list, or a non-empty one, there's no
third case.

Would look like this then:

```scala
object Permutations {
  def permutations[A](list: List[A]): List[List[A]] =
    list match {
      case Nil => List(Nil)
      case _ =>
        shiftN(list, list.length).flatMap {
          case head :: tail =>
            permutations(tail).map(head :: _)
          case _ => Nil
        }
    }

  def shiftN[A](list: List[A], n: Int): List[List[A]] = {
    if (n <= 0) Nil
    else {
      val shifted: List[A] = shift(list)
      shifted :: shiftN(shifted, n - 1)
    }
  }

  def shift[A](list: List[A]): List[A] = list match {
    case head :: tail => tail ++ List(head)
    case _ => Nil
  }
}
```

Lastly, performance-wise it depends what your constraints are: For
`List` input and `List` output, restricting it to single linked lists,
this is fine, though I haven't benchmarked them of
course.  Potentially converting the `shifted :: shiftN(...)` call into
using an accumulator might be worth a bit, instead of having a deep call
stack, but again, it'll probably only matter for longer inputs.

But there are way quicker algorithms, though you might want to copy the
input into a vector that can be accessed in constant time for each
index.  (I found the
[QuickPerm algorithm, as explained here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/array-generate-all-permutations)
absolutely straightforward to implement from scratch.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a another solution using fold that has the similar performance characteristics. One difference is that it doesn't have to compute the linear List Length

```
  def inserts[A](x: A): List[A] => List[List[A]] =
    ls =>
      ls match {
        case Nil       => List(List(x))
        case (y :: ys) => (x :: y :: ys) :: (inserts(x)(ys)).map( y :: _)
      }
  def permutations[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] =
    ls.foldRight(List(List[A]()))((x, xss) => xss.flatMap(inserts(x)))
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. I see an independent solution proposed. `doesn't have to compute [list length]` is a bit thin on [*insight about the code presented for review*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) - CR is *not* about *insight about the problem the code presented is to solve*.